# Swift populating datePicker on edit crashes with nil on save

Tags: ios, swift

Can save item and can load into edit mode populating the datePicker with saved date to firebase.  Converting date to double timeIntervalSince1970.  When I edit the entry whether I change the date from datePicker or just hit save I get a crash with nil value.

```
if let itemToEdit = itemToEdit {
    self.title = "Edit Item"
    itemName.text = itemToEdit.name
    let convertDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: itemToEdit.dueDate)
    itemDueDate.date = convertDate
    itemDueDate.setDate(convertDate, animated: true)
    dueDateChosen = itemToEdit.dueDate
}

@IBAction func itemDueDatePressed(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let pickerDate = itemDueDate.date
    dueDateChosen = pickerDate.timeIntervalSince1970
}

func uploadDocument() {
    var docRef: DocumentReference!
    if let itemName = itemName.text {
        var item = Item.init(id: "", userId: "", categoryId: passedCategoryInfo!.id, name: itemName, dueDate: dueDateChosen, isComplete: isCompleteSwitch.isOn, isImportant: isImportantSwitch.isOn, timeStamp: Timestamp())
```

> Date from Firebase: 1565051728.0
>   Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   2019-07-25 19:48:51.817487-0500 TaskList[21272:2569507] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: I figured it out, I wasn't passing the category on edit

Comment: if segue.identifier == Segues.ToEditItem {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? AddEditCategoryItemTVC {
                if let passedItem = sender as? Item {
                    destinationVC.itemToEdit = passedItem
                    destinationVC.passedCategoryInfo = passedCategory

Comment: Feel free to delete your question.